# When $k$ times composition of a function is a _contraction_

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let  $(X,d)$  be  a  complete  metric  space  and  $$f \ :\ X\rightarrow X$$  be  a   map   such  that  ,  for  some  positive  integer  $k$ ,  $$f\circ f\circ .....\circ f(\ k\ \ fold\ \ composition\ \ with\ \ itself\ )$$  is  a  contraction.

Then  $f$  has  a  unique  fixed  point .

How  should  I  approach  this  problem  $?$

Sorry  for  the   lack  of  efforts  here  .

Please  give  me  some  hints  as  to  how  to  begin  the  thinking  $?$

Answer (score 3):

Use Banach fixed-point theorem then $f^k$ has unique fix point $\alpha$ i.e $f^k (\alpha)=\alpha$ then $f(f^k (\alpha))=\color{red}{f^k(f(\alpha))}=f(\alpha)$thus $f(\alpha)$ is also fixed point, uniqueness implies $f(\alpha)=\alpha$

Answer (score 1):

(I will give a full answer, I am not feeling subtle today)

Let $T = f\circ \ldots \circ f =: f^{(k)} $ (k fold composition of f).

Then surely $T$ is a contraction map?

We will show that one of $f$'s fixed points is in fact $T$'s fixed point:

Let $x$ be the unique fixed point of $T$. Then $f(x) = f(T^m(x))$ for any $m$.

But, $T$ is a stack of $f$'s. So they must commute.

$ f(x) = T^m(f(x))$ for any $m$.

Let $m \to \infty$. So, in particular, the whole space gets crushed to a single point $x$ by $T^m$.

So $f(x) = x$.

Next, showing that this point is unique:

Let $z$ be any fixed point of $f$:

$f(z) = z$

For any m: $T^m(z) = z$ (remember $T$ is just a stack of $f$'s)

Let $m \to \infty .$

Then $x =z$ QED.